# Is there a snowball's chance in Power BI to load DAX logic from a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, m

I have a DAX measure that uses a series of SWITCH statements, to yield a final result of 1, 2, or 3.

The final SWITCH in any branch uses a bunch of hard-coded operators and numeric operands, to determine the final result.  Example:

`SWITCH(TRUE(), Test>=.75, 3, Test>=.50, 2, Test<.50, 1)`

I want to replace the hard-coded text (the operator and numeric operand) via a lookup to a backend SQL Server table.  The table might be as follows:

**`Key      Placeholder    Operator     Operand`**

`Albany     Token1          >=          .75`

`Albany     Token2          >=          .50`

`Albany     Token3          <           .50`

How could I do this?

Currently, I am repeating among different DAX measures these same operators and numeric operands.  When management changes its mind, I must edit each DAX measure by hand.

In SQL or any other programming language, I'd concatenate the static text to the looked-up tokens and then evaluate the resultant string.  I do not know how to do this via DAX in Power BI.

Thanks!

P.S.  A simplified code example (Operator not bothered with), per @Aldert's comment below:

```
Reading1 =

VAR MatchKey = SELECTEDVALUE('Areas'[Cities])
VAR Reading = 'Targets'[MeterReading1]

/***** BOILERPLATE BELOW ****************************************************/

VAR Amt1 = LOOKUPVALUE('Levels'[Operand],'Levels'[Placeholder],"Token1",'Levels'[Key],"MatchKey")
VAR Amt2 = LOOKUPVALUE('Levels'[Operand],'Levels'[Placeholder],"Token2",'Levels'[Key],"MatchKey")
VAR Amt3 = LOOKUPVALUE('Levels'[Operand],'Levels'[Placeholder],"Token3",'Levels'[Key],"MatchKey")

RETURN

SWITCH
(TRUE(),
Reading >= Amt1, "Dead",
Reading >= Amt2, "Nearly Dead",
Reading <  Amt3, "Alive and Glowing",
""
)
```

Comment: You can do this in m-query, the ”back-end” of power-bi

Comment: @Aldert, thanks for replying.  How do I do that, per the notes below?

Right now, I have identical boilerplate lookup-table code that I am copying/pasting into multiple DAX measures.  The few lines of non-boilerplate code assign the unique-to-that-measure lookup keys, which are built from other measures.

So, what I want to do is keep the distinctive DAX but either (1) put the common DAX boilerplate into ONE location and point to it from each DAX measure, or (2) splice the boilerplate into each relevant DAX measure (so that the boilerplate is maintained in ONE splice-source location).

Comment: Please add an example of your source data so I know what you work with and you should also add to your question the DAX you have done so far.

Comment: Please provide some source data so we understand your tables structure (as requested above)

Comment: @Aldert, no one else is replying to this topic.  Do you have an example, per the code I added, that shows how to solve the topic question not in DAX but in M?

Comment: Where is your source data?

Comment: I need it to give you an example in m-query

Comment: Using the above, try "Albany" for MatchKey and ".65" for the Reading.

Comment: Please look at your example. I can see 3 tables (Areas, Targets and Levels). What its their structure (relevant columns) and how do they relate to each other (model). Again: I want to help you but I can not work with half data. Most likely no one can and that is the reason you did not get many responses.